# Python Contraction Function

Tags: python

(I already know there is a library that handles contractions and am able to use it)

BUT....

As a beginner I am trying to also learn how to program in Python, reading text etc.  Here I am trying to do is remove "" and expand contractions.  The removal of the slashes is working just fine. It is the expanding of contractions I am not having luck with.  See my code below

```
contractions = {
"ain't" :"am not",
"aren't": "are not",
"can't": "cannot have",
"'cause": "because",
"could've": "could have",
"couldn't": "could not have",
"didn't": "did not",
"doesn't": "does not",
"don't": "do not",
"hadn't": "had not",
"hadn't've": "had not have",
"hasn't": "has not",    
"haven't": "have not",
"he'd": "he would",
"he'd've": "he would have",
"he'll": "he will",
"he'll've": "he will have",
"he's": "he is",
"how'd": "how did",
"how'd'y": "how do you",
"how'll": "how will",
"how's": "how does",
"i'd": "i would",
"i'd've": "i would have",
"i'll": "i will",
"i'll've": "i will have",
"i'm": "i am",
"i've": "i have",
"isn't": "is not",
"it'd": "it would",
"it'd've": "it would have",
"it'll": "it will",
"it'll've": "it will have",
"it's": "it is",
"let's": "let us",
"ma'am": "madam",
"mayn't": "may not",
"might've": "might have",
"mightn't": "might not",
"must've": "must have",
"mustn't": "must not",
"musn't've": "must not have",
"needn't": "need not",
"needn't've": "need not have",
"o'clock": "of the clock",
"oughtn't": "ought not",
"oughtn't've": "ought not have",
"shan't": "shall not",
"sha'n't": "shall not have",
"she'd": "she would",
"she'd've": "she would have",
"she'll": "she will",
"she'll've": "she will have",
"she's": "she is",
"should've": "should have",
"shouldn't": "should not",
"shouldn't've": "should not have",
"so've": "so have",
"so's": "so is",
"that'd": "that would",
"that'd've": "that would have",
"that's": "that is",
"there'd": "there would",
"they'd":  "they would",
"they'd've": "they would have",
"they'll": "they will",    
"they'll've": "they will have",
"they're": "they are",
"they've": "they have",
"to've": "to have",
"wasn't": "was not",
" u ": "you",
" ur ": "your",
" n ": " and "
}
print(contractions)

def cont_to_exp(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        x= x.replace('\\','')
        for key in contractions:
            value = contractions[key]
            x= x.replace(key,value)
            return x
        else:
            return x
    x="don't"

    print(cont_to_exp(x))
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: That's because you are always returning in the loop.  As soon as you do one replace, you exit.  Don't do that.  Let the whole loop run, and THEN return.

Comment: You have an unconditional `return` statement *inside* your `for` loop.  That makes the loop utterly pointless; only one iteration will take place, so only one of your contractions will get replaced.

Comment: `for key in contractions` - this is not how you use a dictionary object, in general.. Personally, i'd rectify the needless `replace` statements in the loop, though that's really another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must let the whole loop run before returning.

```
print(contractions)

def cont_to_exp(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        x= x.replace('\\','')
        for key,value in contractions.items():
            x = x.replace(key,value)
        return x
x="don't"
print(cont_to_exp(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

`for key in contractions` - this is not how you use a dictionary object, in general. Personally, i'd rectify the needless `replace` statements in the loop, since that can get expensive presumably when the string is overly long.

Though honestly, I'm not sure that you need a loop either - so maybe something like this.

```py
def cont_to_exp(x):
    assert type(x) is str, f"help me, I got a {type(x)}, wanted `str`"
    x= x.replace('\\','')
    for word in x.split():
        if word in contractions:
            x = x.replace(word, contractions[word])

    return x

x="don't hurt me please, haven't you any mercy?"
print(cont_to_exp(x))  # do not hurt me please, have not you any mercy?
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried this and it worked as well.  Enjoy seeing multiple solutions to things.

Comment: That works great if the entire string passed in is a contraction, but it won't replace multiple contractions within a string.

Comment: @CrazyChucky good point, hadn't think of that actually. I updated it slightly to split by words and then check for each one, so I think this version should handle that hopefully.